# Null pointer exception while starting hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate, struts

I am new to struts/hibernate

I downloaded an example from mkyong .. when i deploy the application I get error 
in following line

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
             (SessionFactory) ServletActionContext.getServletContext()
                     .getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME);

ln no.51        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

java.lang.NullPointerException

```
com.mkyong.customer.action.CustomerAction.addCustomer(CustomerAction.java:51)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:843)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:679)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1293)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to

`SessionFactory` hasn't been initialized , due to misconfiguration. please recheck your DB specific conf.

Comment: thanks for the reply .. my hibernate.cfg.xml is fine .. I am able to connect to db with same settings from other application .

Comment: then `ServletActionContext.getServletContext()                     .getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME);` is returning `NULL` , play around it